# Python nonblocking sockets and reliable UDP

Tags: python, sockets, udp, congestion-control

For a graduate-level project, I'm being asked to create a reliable UDP implementation in Python. I have experience with socket programming in Python, but mostly TCP or "fire and forget"-type UDP stuff. I essentially have to create UDP with TCP congestion control. My main question is this:

How can I send packets and receive acknowledgments at the same time? I think the problem is the blocking socket.recv() call. How is this typically handled?

Any help with this or general advice on implementing reliable UDP would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ is a perfect match for your needs, its not very easy for newcomers though.

This blog is a great resource to start from:
http://krondo.com/?page_id=1327

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this a look. Unfortunately, I can't use any external libraries, but it might give me some idea of how to handle my case.

Comment: hmmm, in this case you better take a look at http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#non-blocking-sockets old good select function

Comment: I was actually just looking at that. Thanks!

Comment: one more link before I go... https://github.com/noiseoverip/python-rudp/tree/master/Rudp